# In GCP Cloud Functions what could be the reasons for CPU costs going up by about 40% when invocations only increase by 15%?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cpu-usage

We have a Cloud Function that is invoked by http requests from internet connected devices, it parses the data in the request and inserts the data into BigQuery as nested rows.  In May the Cloud Function cost has increased quite a bit. When I look at the Billing report, it shows that invocations increased month-on-month by about 15% but CPU usage and costs are showing as having increased by 40%.

Apart from 10% small increase in number of invocations, I don't believe the nature of the invocations has changed at all and I'm not seeing any errors.

Is there anything that would explain why CPU usage would have increased?

I've looked at the billing reports to look at month-on-month invocations and CPU usage, but don't have any insight as to what has caused CPU usage to increase or where to look next.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because billing questions should be addressed to the vendor's customer service. We have no access to your account to investigate any issues. Asking us to speculate about what might be causing a problem for you is not a specific programming related question.

Comment: Check the volume of request and CPU/Memory time that you use per month, and perform the calculation by taking into account the free tiers. If the 15% traffic increase is above the free tiers, the 40% billing increase is not surprising!

Comment: You can click this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) to help you with your billing concerns.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. Apologies if I asked a question outside the scope of this platform, but the two answers by Guillaume and Dominic are helpful.